# Compatibility issues with package developed on OS X10.6.4 on older OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode3.2, packagemaker

I am using Os X 10.6.4 and X code Version 3.2.3 for developing some simple app files and using PackageMaker to distribute these app files. But when trying to run the package on some other mac I am getting error that the package is not compatible with the Os X its running and file would not be installed.
Is this a problem with X code or package maker. Any idea or solution about it?

thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Although I tried changing base SDK to 10.5, it was getting compiled and ran well on mac I am using for development (Mac OS X 10.6.4) but when installed on mac running OS X 10.5 the .app files were grayed out and message poped up saying 'you cannot use this version of application with this version of Mac'. Any idea why is this happening? Also as mentioned earlier I am using IBOutlet for accepting user date from form and then writing that into a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Project Settings and change your base SDK from 10.6 to 10.4 or 10.5.

Comment: I did tried that but then its giving me an error that "cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSApplicationDelegate' "
I am using NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> to accept some user input and store it in text file....any thought on this...?

Comment: NSApplicationDelegate is 10.6 only. I believe you can simply remove < NSApplication> from your header declaration, and the app will still work. They promoted NSApplicationDelegate from an informal protocol to a formal one in 10.6.

Comment: cool..it worked for me. I hope removing NSApplicationDelegate will not create any other problems, but its working fine with base SDK as 10.5 and GCC 4.2 as well as 4.0 but with SDK 10.4 its giving error that GCC is not compatible. Can I do anything to make compatible with 10.4 but if not I guess 10.5 is sufficient fot me. Now I can create a new package with minimum target as OS X10.5 right? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Try choosing GCC 4.0, if you have that installed with your SDK.